# Converting a numpy array into a tensor

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have just started learning about machine learning using tensorflow.I am basically trying to use the Iris dataset, and what I would like to do is convert a numpy array into a tensor.So I read my dataset using pandas.read_csv(), and then convert it into a numpy array, following which I would like to convert it into a tensor.But for some reason, I get an error while doing so.

```
Following is the code :

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.utils import shuffle

data =pd.read_csv('###filepath####')
data=shuffle(data)
print type(data)
print data.values
data=np.asarray(data)
print type(data)
data_tf1 = tf.convert_to_tensor(data)

The error displayed is as follows:
TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got 5.6
```

Now the dataset consists of 5 rows, 4 out of which are of the type float, and one is a string.The dataset does get converted into a numpy array, and I am also able to retrieve the values, but converting the same into a tensor is where the issue lies.

What I would like to know is:
Can a numpy array consisting of values with different datatypes be converted into a tensor?

P.s:I know there could be alternate approaches to this, I am trying my best to figure them all out, I just want to know if my query is a valid one,or is there no way of getting it done.

Comment: As far as I know, all the values in a tensor should be of the same type, e.g. `tf.float32` or `tf.float64` and you specify the type using the parameter `dtype`. Why do you want different datatypes inside a tensor anyway?

Comment: So what if I have a dataset that consists of numerical as well as string data,and I would want to use them both, is there no way to get it done?I am just a little confused here

Comment: Yes, you transform the string data into numeric format. Since you're talking about the iris dataset, you could assign `setosa` to 0.0, `versicolor` to 1.0 and `virginica` to 2.0. This is quite standard when dealing with categorical features/labels in machine learning

Comment: In Python there are a few ways to convert categorical data into numeric data, for example `LabelEncoder`. Have a look here for example http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html

Comment: Ok then, I will try that, just to clear my doubt, a tensor cannot have values with multiple datatypes right?

Comment: As far as I know it's not possible (although I can't find it explicitly stated in the official documentation...). However I've built myself a multilayer perceptron and a recurrent neural network in tensorflow by following several tutorials on the net and I've never seen a single tensor using mixed datatypes (which makes sense given the kind of computations performed in a neural network...).

Comment: Ok, I get it now, Thank you so much.